# Express Negation in Simple English: There is a student in this class who has chatted with exactly one other student

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic, logic-translation

Am I correct in the following:

If the domain is all students, and C(x,y) is the predicate of x having chatted with y. Then the sentence

> There is a student in this class who has chatted with exactly one other student

Can be represented as
$$\exists x\exists y(y\ne x\land \forall z(z\ne x\to(z=y\leftrightarrow C(x,z))))$$

Which is logically equivalent to:

$$\exists x \exists y[(x\neq y) \land\forall z ([z=x] \lor[(z\neq y) \lor C(x,y)] \land [\lnot C(x,y) \lor (z = y)])]$$

The negation of which would be:

$$\forall x \forall y [(x=y) \lor \exists z([z\neq x] \land [(z =y) \land \lnot C(x,y)] \lor[C(x,y) \land(z \neq y)])]$$

That is also logically equivalent to:

$$\forall x \forall y [(x = y) \lor \exists z([z \neq x] \land [C(x,y) \leftrightarrow (z \neq y)])]$$

Which can be translated to: All students have spoken with at least one other student or themselves?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As coffeemath indicated, the negation should of course end up being that every student either ends up chatting with no other students, or with *two* or more.

However, the logic expression you got at the end does not translate as such. And that's because you made a small mistake. Note that your $C(x,z)$ became $C(x,y)$, and that should not have happened. Indeed, you final expression should have been:

$$\forall x \ \forall y (x =y \lor \exists z (z \not = x \land [C(x,z) \leftrightarrow z \not =y]))$$

Ok, but how does *that* mean that every student ends up chatting with no other students, or with two or more? That is still not immediately obvious, so let me explain.

First, I would recommend rewriting it as:

$\forall x \ \forall y (x \not = y \rightarrow \exists z (z \not = x \land [C(x,z) \leftrightarrow z \not = y])) \tag{1}$

This is still hard to parse in English, but at least it starts with two different students $x$ and $y$ and now of course we want to make sure that either they didn't chat at all, or that they did chat but there is a third student $z$ that $x$ chatted with as well. In other words, we want to show that *if* $x$ and $y$ did chat, then there must be some third student $z$ that $x$ chatted with as well.

Ok, so let's suppose $x$ and $y$ chatted. Given $(1)$ and given that $x$ and $y$ are different, we know that there is some $z$ that is different from $x$ such that $C(x,z) \leftrightarrow z \not =y$.

Now, if $z=y$ then the right side is false, and hence the left side is false as well, and hence $x$ did not chat with $z=y$ .. but we assumed $x$ did chat with $y$, so we have a problem. So, $z$ is some other than $y$, and therefore $x$ did chat with $z$.

And so there you go: as soon as $x$ chats with some other student $y$, then there has to be some third student $z$ that $x$ chats with as well.

Answer (score 3):

The negation would be: For all students x, either x has chatted with no other students or x has chatted with more than one other student.

[This is just ruling out x chatting with exactly one other student.]

Comment: How does $\exists z([z \neq x] \land [C(x,y) \leftrightarrow (z \neq y)])$ mean more than one?

Comment: @Elliott I was negating the statement in yellow of OP's posted question. The sentence of your comment is one the OP obtained, and I didn't think it was right.